# Pm2 restarts not work properly for long hours and exceed restart limit

Tags: configuration, devops, pm2

I have acrually three services running.
Service 2 is dependent on service 1. As soon as I stop service 1 manually service 2 should stop as well after 10 retries. It works fine for initial few hours but it does not work that way after like 11-12 hours. I am really confused how to manage this and stop my service 2 after 10 retries how much I should increase min-uptime to make it work as expected.

```
  GNU nano 6.2                                                   service-runner.json                                                            
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "ipfs-runner",
      "script": "./script.sh",
      "delay": 5000 ,
      "log-file-max-size": "10M",
      "max_size":"10M",
      "max_restarts": 5,
      "error_file": "./logs/debug-ipfs.log",
      "error_size": "10M"
    },
    {
      "name": "ipfs-cluster-runner",
      "script": "./startup.sh",
      "delay": 10000,
      "log-file-max-size": "10M",
      "max_size":"10M",
      "max_restarts": 5,
      "error_file": "./logs/debug-cluster.log",
      "error_size": "10M",
      "min_uptime": 10000
    },
    {
      "name": "file-server-runner",
      "script": "./file-server-lin",
      "delay": 10000,
      "log-file-max-size": "10M",
      "max_size":"10M",
      "max_restarts": 10,
      "error_file": "./logs/debug-file.log",
      "error_size": "10M",
      "min_uptime": 3600000
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried increasing the min-uptime period as I got some suggestions it would work. Although it worked better but not perfectly. As before increasing min-uptime restarts exceeds after like an hour

Comment: Can you please provide more informations?
How do you detect service 1 is down?
How do you stop service 2?

Comment: I have a usecase where due to some reasons service 1 gets done and its done purposely.
So when service 1 is down service 2 detect it internally and exits.

This is implemented and tested but pm2 gets into troubles when long hours are passed and it exceed restarts.